# Where is the program counter stored during thread context switch?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system

When I call `pthread_yield` or `pthread_block` and the CPU does a context switch

Is the program counter stored in the **thread stack** (alongside its temporary registers) or in the **thread control block** (alongside the stack pointer)

Comment: Context switches are implemented by the OS kernel.  TCB is a convenient abstraction for the actual storage location.  It just doesn't matter, you are not going to do anything different if you'd knew the real details.

Comment: Usually, on a stack, since the thread is usually dispatched onto a core by means of an interrupt-return, which pops the PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it shall be in the TCB. But I beleive it is implementation specific.
An example of information contained within a TCB is:

- Thread Identifier:Unique id (tid) is assigned to every new thread
- Stack pointer: Points to thread's stack in the process
- Program counter
- State of the thread (running, ready, waiting, start, done)
- Thread's register values
- Pointer to the Process control block (PCB) of the process that the thread lives on

Comment: Well, since the PC is pushed during a hardware interrupt, software interrupt and the syscall mechanisms I know of, the PC should not need explicit storage - it's on a stack.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [VxWorks:APPLICATION PROGRAMMER’S GUIDE](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/fys/FYS4220/h11/undervisningsmateriale/laboppgaver-rt/VxWorks-6.2_Application_Programmers_Guide.pdf),page 76:

> Each task has its own context, which is the CPU environment and system resources that the task sees each time it is scheduled to run by the kernel. On a context switch, a task’s context is saved in the task control block(TCB).
>
> A task’s context includes:
>
> ■a thread of execution; that is, the task’s **program counter**
>
> ■the tasks’ virtual memory context (if process support is included)
>
> ■the CPU registers and (optionally) coprocessor registers
>   stacks for dynamic variables and function calls
>
> ■I/O assignments for standard input, output, and error
>
> ■a delay timer
>
> ■a time-slice timer
>
> ■kernel control structures
>
> ■signal handlers
>
> ■task variables
>
> ■error status (errno)
>
> ■debugging and performance monitoring values